# Interaction between api gateway (Zuul) and UAA server (Spring OAuth2) with Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to build a system with an gateway server (Zuul), and UAA server (Spring OAuth2)
There's lots of examples but they are all used with Spring Boot 1 (1.5.X?). When I tried to migrate to Spring Boot 2, lots of things got moved or removed (in the auto-configure package).

My current understanding is that the gateway server will acts as an oauth2 client with sso. Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks.